# Is Agda sound as a proof system?

Tags: logic, proof-assistants

I was browsing Agda's stdlib source code, since I was trying to get into it seriously and therefore wanted to know more. I was amazed at that Agda is way more developed than I thought and it's significantly much closer to Haskell than Coq.

However, I was quite a bit panicked when I see some code like following:

```
toList∘fromList : ∀ s → toList (fromList s) ≡ s
toList∘fromList s = trustMe
```

It seems there is an observable hole in the system, and it means Agda is not entirely built from ground up by axiomization. Then I saw this,

https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/src/Data/Colist.agda

```
data Colist {a} (A : Set a) : Set a where
  []  : Colist A
  _∷_ : (x : A) (xs : ∞ (Colist A)) → Colist A
```

I took `Colist` is the same as `List` in Haskell, allowing optionally infinite length, and from Wiki https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.3/language/coinduction.html

> The type constructor ∞ can be used to prove absurdity!

Just as I suspected, optional infinity introduces absurdity. To this point, I felt I was more scared than amazed.

I understand that being practical must come with some trade off. However, Agda is more or less considered as a proof system, arguably more than a progarmming language. There are lots of papers these days are based on Agda. However, a quick code scan has shown holes in many disguises. (Sure Coq also has that, but it's considerably easy to discover: just grep axiom, admit will tell a lot, and Coq supports printing axioms for each lemma.)

Since I am trying to enter Agda, I have no idea what I should expect from it. So the title says all my question: are the system and the results based on it, sound?

Comment: really nobody wants to answer this question?

Comment: is it a good idea to ask this question on cstheory, in case there can be more attention on that platform.

Comment: I encourage you to have some more patience.  This is a small site; sometimes it can take a few days for people to see the question.  You could consider setting a bounty if you want to try to gather more attention to the question, but I'd recommend just giving it a little time.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/40439/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/89611/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.